# HTTP Basic authentication for a Jetty server

Tags: authentication, jetty

How do I enable HTTP basic authentication to a Jetty server which runs as a service. I want this to be a server configuration regardless of the contexts that it runs (i.e. I don't want to have to modify the web.xml).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this answers your question: [Jetty webserver security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323855/jetty-webserver-security/5332049#5332049)